# Payzone Hashdigest not matching

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to integrate payzone payment in wordpress and getting some error. I've done some code to take remaining payment after the order is processed via woocommerce..The site takes certain amount via woocommerce payzone plugin and final amount via custom payzone hosted form..The error im getting is below:

"This transaction cannot be processed. The submitted data was rejected for a SECURITY reason: HashDigest does not match."

The merchant detials are correct and working fine with woocommerce but custom integration is giving me errors..I tried but couldnt trackt the error yet! Below is my code to create the hashdigest

```
public static function calculate_hash_digest($string, $pre_shared_key, $hash_method) {
    switch($hash_method) {
        case "MD5":
        $hash_digest = md5($string);
        break;
        case "SHA1":
        $hash_digest = sha1($string);
        break;
        case "HMACMD5":
        $hash_digest = hash_hmac("md5", $string, $pre_shared_key);
        break;
        case "HMACSHA1":
        $hash_digest = hash_hmac("sha1", $string, $pre_shared_key);
        break;
    }
    return $hash_digest;
}

public static function get_country_code($country_code) {
    $code = 826;
    switch ($country_code ) {
        case 'GB':
        $code = 826;
        break;
        case 'US':
        $code  = 840;
        break;
        case 'AU':
        $code  = 36;
        break;
        case 'CA':
        $code  = 124;
        break;
        default;
        $code = 826;
        break;
    }

    return $code;
}

public static function payzone_settings($key) {
    $settings = get_option('woocommerce_payzone_settings');
    if($key) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $settings)) {
            return $settings[$key];
        }
    }
    else {
        return $settings;
    }
}


public static function generate_string_to_hash(
    $merchant_id,
    $merchant_password,
    $amount,
    $country_code,
    $order_id,
    $transaction_type,
    $transaction_date_time,
    $callback_url,
    $order_description,
    $customer_name,
    $billing_address_1,
    $billing_address_2,
    $billing_address_3,
    $billing_address_4,
    $billing_city,
    $billing_state,
    $billing_postcode,
    $billing_country,
    $CV2_mandatory,
    $address1_mandatory,
    $city_mandatory,
    $postcode_mandatory,
    $state_mandatory,
    $country_mandatory,
    $result_delivery_method,
    $server_result_url,
    $payment_form_displays_result,
    $pre_shared_key,
    $hash_method,
    $billing_email,
    $billing_phone
)
{
    $return_string = "";
    switch($hash_method) {
        case "MD5":
        $include_pre_shared_key_in_string = true;
        break;
        case "SHA1":
        $include_pre_shared_key_in_string = true;
        break;
        case "HMACMD5":
        $include_pre_shared_key_in_string = false;
        break;
        case "HMACSHA1":
        $include_pre_shared_key_in_string = false;
        break;
    }
    if($include_pre_shared_key_in_string) {
        $return_string = "PreSharedKey=" . $pre_shared_key . "&";
    }
    $return_string .=
    "MerchantID=" .
    $merchant_id .
    "&Password=" .
    $merchant_password.
    "&Amount=" .
    $amount .
    "&CurrencyCode=" .
    $country_code .
    "&EchoAVSCheckResult=true" .
    "&EchoCV2CheckResult=true" .
    "&EchoThreeDSecureAuthenticationCheckResult=true" .
    "&EchoCardType=true" .
    "&OrderID=" .
    $order_id .
    "&TransactionType=" .
    $transaction_type .
    "&TransactionDateTime=" .
    $transaction_date_time .
    "&CallbackURL=" .
    $callback_url .
    "&OrderDescription=" .
    $order_description .
    "&CustomerName=" .
    $customer_name .
    "&Address1=" .
    $billing_address_1 .
    "&Address2=" .
    $billing_address_2 .
    "&Address3=" .
    $billing_address_3.
    "&Address4=" .
    $billing_address_4.
    "&City=" .
    $billing_city .
    "&State=" .
    $billing_state .
    "&PostCode=" .
    $billing_postcode .
    "&CountryCode=" .
    $billing_country .
    "&EmailAddress=" .
    $billing_email .
    "&PhoneNumber=" .
    $billing_phone .
    "&CV2Mandatory=" .
    $CV2_mandatory .
    "&Address1Mandatory=" .
    $address1_mandatory .
    "&CityMandatory=" .
    $city_mandatory .
    "&PostCodeMandatory=" .
    $postcode_mandatory .
    "&StateMandatory=" .
    $state_mandatory .
    "&CountryMandatory=" .
    $country_mandatory .
    "&ResultDeliveryMethod=
    ".$result_delivery_method."
    &ServerResultURL=" .
    $server_result_url .
    "&PaymentFormDisplaysResult=" .
    $payment_form_displays_result.
    "&ServerResultURLCookieVariables=" .
    "&ServerResultURLFormVariables=" .
    "&ServerResultURLQueryStringVariables=";

    return $return_string;
}

public static function get_hosted_payment_form_args(
    $callback_url,
    $server_result_url,
    $order_id,
    $amount = 0
) {
    $order                 = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $transaction_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s P');
    $currency              = get_option('woocommerce_currency');
    $country_code          = self::get_country_code($currency);
    $settings              = self::payzone_settings();
    $mode                  = $settings['test_mode'];
    $merchant_id           = $mode == 'yes' ? $settings['test_mid'] : $settings['live_mid'];
    $merchant_password     = $mode == 'yes' ? $settings['test_password'] : $settings['live_password'];
    $pre_shared_key        = $settings['pre_shared_key'];
    $hash_method           = $settings['hash_method'];
    $transaction_type      = $settings['transaction_type'];
    $string_to_hash =
    self::generate_string_to_hash(
        $merchant_id,
        $merchant_password,
        $amount,
        $country_code ,
        $order->get_id(),
        $transaction_type,
        $transaction_date_time,
        $callback_url,
        'Rental Remaining Payment for Order '.$order->get_id(),
        $order->billing_first_name.' '.$order->billing_last_name,
        $order->billing_address_1,
        $order->billing_address_2,
        '',
        '',
        $order->billing_city,
        $order->billing_state,
        $order->billing_postcode,
        $country_code,
        "true",
        "false",
        "false",
        "false",
        "false",
        "false",
        'POST',
        $server_result_url,
        'false',
        $pre_shared_key ,
        $hash_method,
        $order->billing_email,
        $order->billing_phone
    ); 

    return array(
        'HashDigest' => self::calculate_hash_digest($string_to_hash , $pre_shared_key, $hash_method),
        'MerchantID' => $merchant_id,
        'Amount' => (string) $amount,
        'CurrencyCode' => (string) $country_code ,
        'EchoAVSCheckResult' => "true",
        'EchoCV2CheckResult' => "true",
        'EchoThreeDSecureAuthenticationCheckResult' => "true",
        'EchoCardType' => "true",
        'OrderID' => (string) $order->get_id(),
        'TransactionType' => $transaction_type,
        'TransactionDateTime' => $transaction_date_time,
        'CallbackURL' => $callback_url,
        'OrderDescription' =>  'Rental Remaining Payment for Order '.$order->get_id(),
        'CustomerName' => $order->billing_first_name.' '.$order->billing_last_name,
        'Address1' => $order->billing_address_1,
        'Address2' => $order->billing_address_2,
        'Address3' => "",
        'Address4' => "",
        'City' => $order->billing_city,
        'State' => $order->billing_state,
        'Postcode' => $order->billing_postcode,
        'CountryCode' => (string) $country_code,
        'EmailAddress' => $order->billing_email,
        'PhoneNumber' => $order->billing_phone,
        'CV2Mandatory' => "true",
        'Address1Mandatory' => "false",
        'CityMandatory' => "false",
        'PostCodeMandatory' => "false",
        'StateMandatory' => "false",
        'CountryMandatory' => "false",
        'ResultDeliveryMethod' => 'POST',
        'ServerResultURL' => $server_result_url,
        'PaymentFormDisplaysResult' => 'false',
        'ServerResultURLCookieVariables' => "",
        'ServerResultURLFormVariables' => "",
        'ServerResultURLQueryStringVariables' => ""
    );
}
```

Any help is really appreciated!!